# Why is there no chat in the footer on Stack Overflow like on other sites?

Tags: support, chat, footer

On all Stack Exchange sites there is a chat in the footer why is there none at Stack Overflow? Usually I find it over Google or a bookmark, but I was wondering why it is this way.

Comment: Off topic here since it applies to single site only (Stack Overflow) and it was [already asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361536/where-did-the-stack-overflow-chat-link-go) here, then migrated to MSO. :)

Comment: Oh I thought I was on so meta. They look so similar :P That explains why I didn't find this question already

Comment: Can I ask how you arrived here then? It might explain some of the off topic questions we get here that belongs to SO. (main, not meta. :))

Comment: I am actually not sure anymore. I'm trying to reproduce, but I'm myself not sure how I landed on se meta and not on so meta, well :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow's footer is different in many aspects; not surprisingly, since it's the biggest site in the network with a lot of 'side features' like the [salary calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) and [Stack Overflow for Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise).

There *is* another way to reach Stack Overflow Chat, via the Stack Exchange logo at the right of the top bar:

[image]